# How To Properly Use realloc On A 2D Array In C++

Tags: c++, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am trying to use take realloc a 2D array but I keep getting a Segmentation Fault and it seems to almost positively be stemming from how I am reallocating my 2D array. The array is initially specified to be a size of 3 x 26. My goal is to simple reallocate the first array (3) and just multiply it by 2 while keeping the other arrays all a size of 26.

```
//Array creation
 int ** array_creation (){
    int ** arr = (int **) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(int *));
        if(arr==NULL){
            cout<<"malloc fail"<<endl;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<buffer_size;i++){
            arr[i] = (int *)malloc(26 * sizeof(int));
            if(arr[i]==NULL){
                cout<<"malloc fail"<<endl;
            }
        }
    return arr;
}
//Variables
buffer_size = 3;
buffer_count = 0;
 if(buffer_count >= buffer_size){
        cout<<"Doubling the size of dynamic arrays!"<<endl;
        buffer_size = buffer_size * 2;
        // arr = (int **) realloc(arr, buffer_size * sizeof(int));
}
```

So once the buffer_size is equal to the buffer_count I want to just double the first array that would start at 3, so make the 2D array go from 3 array of 26 integers to 6 arrays of 26 integers.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why not remove all the manual array memory management and use `std::vector` ?

Comment: Apart from using `std::vector` – if you insist on raw arrays then `new[]` and `delete[]` is more C++-like...

Comment: You don't really have a 2D array here. All you have is an addressing syntax similar to a 2D array. You actually have a non-contiguous array of arrays.

Comment: The `realloc` function only reallocates the memory that you pass to the function, which for your case (when you fix [the `sizeof` problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74741061/440558)) will enlarge the array of pointers, but it will ***not*** initialize the new elements of that array. You will end up with an array that contains uninitialized pointers that can't be used.

Comment: Also remember that if `realloc` fails, it will return a null pointer, but still leave the original memory untouched. If you assign back to the pointer you pass as argument then you will loose that original memory, leading to a *leak*.

Comment: And as a general note, whenever you must or feel the need to use C-style casting in your C++ program, you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong. Also, `NULL` is a C backward compatible macro, which shouldn't really be used in C++ any more. Use `nullptr` for null pointers. Lastly, please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to learn C++ properly, not C in C++.

Comment: I am required to use the realloc as a specification for this project. I agree that using vector would be much easier as well as using new.

Comment: Is this the *complete* code??? There seems to be a free-standing `if` and your `array_creation` function isn't called anywhere. As is, the code won't compile at all. Please create a [mre]!

Comment: About the `std::vector` – what exactly are your requirements? Note that you might at least use a `std::vector<int*>` to store the manually allocated pointer arrays – and the `int**` pointer (if you e.g. need to pass it to some C API) you can get from via `myVector.data()` (or `&myVector[0]` for pre-C++11 code)! Only exception to: If the `int**` pointer is passed to some data sink that is going to clean it up by use of `free`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your malloc

```
int ** arr = (int **) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(int *));
```

Now look at your realloc

```
arr = (int **) realloc(arr, buffer_size * sizeof(int));
```

See the difference? It should be `sizeof(int *)` for both cases.

Comment: This is still not correct usage of `realloc`!

Comment: @Aconcagua How so?

Comment: I would guess their point is that it relies on the realloc succeeding. The proper way is to store the result in another variable and null-check it before overwriting your original.

Comment: OK noted, although I think it's also perfectly reasonable to ignore the possibility of memory exhaustion.

Comment: @john This argumentation leads to undefined behaviour on dereferencing the nullpointer. On modern OS this would most likely lead to crash (segmentation fault), on MCU this can actually be a valid address, then usually the start address of your programme. You'd render your MCU unstartable if writing a bad value to...

Comment: @john -- but the original code doesn't ignore the possibility of memory exhaustion; it checks the value returned by `malloc` consistently.

Comment: @PeteBecker The original code attempts to print an error message when `malloc` returns NULL but then goes ahead and uses the pointer anyway, thus invoking undefined behaviour and invalidating the entire program. I don't think you can read too much into the OPs code, since they are clearly a beginner,

Comment: @john -- nevertheless, the code does not "ignore the possibility of memory exhaustion", even though it doesn't handle it sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

Correct usage of `realloc` (in general) looks as follows; note that you need a temporary variable to hold the result of the reallocation because you'd lose the old pointer on failure otherwise:

```
auto tmp = realloc(thePointer, newSize);
if(tmp)
{
    // cast here or earlier, doesn't matter
    thePointer = static_cast<decltype(thePointer)>(tmp);
}
else
{
    // appropriate error handling; note how `thePointer` remainded
    // unchanged and you still have access to the previous array,
    // so you might e.g. free it to avoid memory leaks
}
```

In your specific case the pointer type is `int**`, the new size is `buffer_size * sizeof(int*)` (note that you missed an asterisk there in your code!).

However usage of malloc/realloc is discouraged in C++. You avoid all this memory management hassle if you use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the help. When I tried to update that line to arr = (int **) realloc(arr, buffer_size * sizeof(int *)); it still is giving me the Segmentation Fault. Thanks again for the help, like I said I am required to use the realloc on it and I know it is not best.

Comment: @ibucksss You haven't provided a [mre] – in these little fragments you provided there's too much lacking. A complete working example might look like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/58xae9d8b) – note, though, that, instead of allocating all sub-arrays immediately, it would be better to initialise all positions in `arr` to `nullptr` instead and only `malloc` such a sub-array on increasing `buffer_count`.